# Экранирование символов в Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, экранирование

```
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/include LIBS+=C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib"
```

После формируются Makefile'ы.

```
mingw32-make #или просто make
```

выдает:

```
...
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -
Wextra -DUNICODE -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_DLL -DQT_PLU
GIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT
_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"c:\Qt\4.8.6\include\QtCore" -I"c:\Qt\4.8.6\inc
lude\QtSql" -I"c:\Qt\4.8.6\include" -I"c:\Program" -I"Files\MySQL\MySQL" -I"Serv
er" -I"5.6\include" -I"LIBS+=C:\Program" -I"Files\MySQL\MySQL" -I"Server" -I"5.6
\lib" -I"c:\Qt\4.8.6\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"c:\Qt\4.8.6\mkspecs\default"
 -o debug\main.o main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:44:0:
../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.h:52:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such fil
e or directory
 #include <mysql.h>
...
```

Видно, что пробелы неэкранированы. Но я никак не могу найти нужный символ.

^, \ и / не действуют.
\ выдает ошику еще на qmake, как и попытка заключить нужную сроку в '.

Comment: Сделал несколько иначе: добавил эту строку в *.pro файл с кавычками - и пришел к выводу, что можно было сделать именно так, как вы предложили. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

А так пробовали:

```
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=^"C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/include^" LIBS+=^"C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib^""
```

?